# How Do you Drag-Move a Row in NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

If it were an **iOS** project, letting the user drag-move the selected row would be relatively easy.  I think it's something like

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    // ...
}
```

How do you do it with **NSTableView** (not UITableView in iOS) in **Mac OS** if I have a **cell-based** table?  One sample project by Apple, Inc. that lets the user drag items is **image-browser**, which doesn't quite help because it doesn't involve an NSTableView control.  Do you use **canDragRowsWithIndexes**:atPoint?  I don't get many search hits with canDragRowsWithIndexes.  If I run a search for "NSTableView reorder," I get hits for sorting table items.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I've found a sample project at http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/074-NSTableView-drag-drop.pl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use these methods:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView acceptDrop:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)info row:(NSInteger)row dropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)operation

- (NSDragOperation)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView validateDrop:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)info proposedRow:(NSInteger)row proposedDropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)operation

- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard
```

[This guide](http://www.corbinstreehouse.com/blog/2005/07/drag-and-drop-in-an-nstableview/) by Corbin Dunn is a little old but should get you there well.

Comment: Thanks.  I would like more assistance in implementing those methods.  Running a search for them gives me little help except that it seems that I need to register a drag type of some sort for the tableview control.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  Yes, the said web site gives me a lot of clue though the most crucial part, acceptDrop, is incomplete.  Meanwhile, the sample project available at the link that I posted in the first comment can complement it to some extent (not completely).

Comment: I don't know how it works, honestly.  But I've somehow managed to drag-move a row with the combination of code at the link posted by Wain and the sample project.  Life is so complicated these days.

Comment: @TBlue: `writeRowsWithIndexes:` is the “drag” method and the other two are the “drop” methods. In `writeRowsWithIndexes:`, you put your items (or identifiers of them) onto the pasteboard, and in `acceptDrop:`, you retrieve those items and move or duplicate them as warranted by the drag operation.