# How to reorder rows in NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I just can't seem to find a quick and easy way to simply reorder rows in an NSTableView (the OSX one, not iOS). On iOS I would use these two delegate methods:

```
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    MyObject *obj = [model objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [model removeObject:obj]; 
    [model insertObject:obj atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
}
```

Is there any quick and easy way to do something similar for an NSTableView in Cocoa? So far I have only found some extensive code samples using the pasteboard, which seemed pretty much like an overkill for a simple reordering functionality to me.

Comment: Reorder the datasource and tell the tableview to redraw.

Comment: That part is clear to me - my problem is the actual dragging to reorder. on iOS, that is already implemented and happens automatically. I want to reproduce a similar behavior for the NSTableView, i.e. click and hold, then drag the row to a new position.

Comment: It's more generalized under OSX as it's used for drag-and-drop (i.e. you could allow a file to be dragged from *Finder* into your tableview).  Look at the [Dragging](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000118-SW150) section of the `NSTableView` class reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939623/how-do-you-drag-move-a-row-in-nstableview

Comment: thanks, found a simple solution via @ElTomato s link. I'm posting my easy-to-copy code as the solution to this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks guys, this is what worked for me perfectly now:

```
//add line somewhere in your code
#define MyPrivateTableViewDataType @"MyPrivateTableViewDataType"

//add line in your viewDidLoad: method
[self.tableView registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:MyPrivateTableViewDataType]
```

these data source methods can be copied to the code without any alteration:

```
// drag operation stuff
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)pboard {
    // Copy the row numbers to the pasteboard.
    NSData *zNSIndexSetData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:rowIndexes];

    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:MyPrivateTableViewDataType] owner:self];

    [pboard setData:zNSIndexSetData forType:MyPrivateTableViewDataType];

    return YES;
}

- (NSDragOperation)tableView:(NSTableView*)tv validateDrop:(id )info proposedRow:(NSInteger)row proposedDropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)op {
    // Add code here to validate the drop
    return NSDragOperationEvery;
}
```

this part needs to implement the custom model, just like in my question above:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView acceptDrop:(id )info row:(NSInteger)row dropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)operation {

    NSPasteboard* pboard = [info draggingPasteboard];
    NSData* rowData = [pboard dataForType:MyPrivateTableViewDataType];
    NSIndexSet* rowIndexes = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:rowData];
    NSInteger dragRow = [rowIndexes firstIndex];





    if (dragRow < row) {
        [model insertObject:[model objectAtIndex:dragRow] atIndex:row];
        [model removeObjectAtIndex:dragRow];

        [aTableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged];
        [aTableView moveRowAtIndex:dragRow toIndex:row-1];

    }else {
        ModelObj *obj = [model objectAtIndex:dragRow];
        [model removeObjectAtIndex:dragRow];
        [model insertObject:obj atIndex:row];

        [aTableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged];
        [aTableView moveRowAtIndex:dragRow toIndex:row];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Copied from here http://juliuspaintings.co.uk/cgi-bin/paint_css/animatedPaint/074-NSTableView-drag-drop.pl

Comment: @optz this worked perfectly for me -- save me a ton of time!  Thanks for posting it!  ONE NOTE:  I tried to use NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleGap, which did NOT work properly when dragging from the bottom UPWARD -- it doesn't create a gap for the 2nd to bottom row, resulting in overprinting the moved row text when dragging.  Dragging from the TOP DOWNWARD does work.  I fell back on NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyleRegular.